# How to send Select Option Text instead of Value on form post?

Tags: jquery, razor, sharepoint, asp.net-core

I have a SelectList that's being created dynamically with jQuery:

```
<script>
    //Create and Append Select List
    var sel = $('#MealTierDiv');
    sel.append(
        $('<select />').attr({
            'id': 'MealTier',
            'onChange': 'calculatePrice()',
            'asp-for' : 'MealTier'
        }).append(
            $('<option />', { value:@Model.PriceBasic, text: 'Basic' }),
            $('<option />', { value:@Model.PriceMiddle, text: 'Middle' }),
            $('<option />', { value:@Model.PriceHigh, text: 'High' })
        )
    );

</script>
```

And this successfully creates the SelectList on my Razor view with the appropriate options:

`<option value="10">Basic</option>` etc. for each of the options.

CalculatePrice looks like this:

```
<script>
        function calculatePrice() {
            var y = document.getElementById("EstimatedCost");
            var x = document.getElementById("NumberOfAttendees");
            var z = document.getElementById("MealTier");
            y.value = x.value * z.value;
        }
    </script>
```

Essentially I am reading the value from the Select Options and multiplying them by NumberOfAttendees (which is an input field).  The calculations work correctly and on Sharepoint's end I see the estimated cost calculates and saves properly but I suspect the reason I am not getting "10" instead of "Basic" for the Select is the whole Value vs Text thing.

I need the values because the `calculatePrice` method takes the value of the select list item and multiplies it by an input field's value and updates a 3rd, readonly input to display an estimated price.  These items are being saved to Sharepoint and when I go to view the actual Sharepoint list item, the value here is blank and I suspect it's because it's a field expecting a string value and it's being sent the numbers from `value` rather than the string from `text`.

What do I need to do so that when my form posts I send the `text` to `Model.MealTier` rather than the `value`?

Comment: You could put the text in the value and put the value in a data-* field that could be used in your calculatePrice method.  Otherwise you'll have to find the selected option of the select and get it's `html()` or `text()`.  Which is kinda only valid for ajax requests.

Comment: @Taplar Could you explain how to do this?  I am very new to jQuery.  I'll add the calculate method so you can see what it's doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just before you submit (and after any calculations ) set each option's value as it's text:

```
$('#formId').submit(function(){
    $('#MealTier option').val(function(){
       return $(this).text();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  You and Taplar were both extremely helpful in showing me different ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//just showing how you could find the selected option for your calc method.
$('#MealTier').on('change', function(e){
  console.log($(e.target).find('option:selected').data('cost'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="MealTier">
  <option value="Basic" data-cost="10.00">Basic</option>
  <option value="Extra" data-cost="15.99">Extra</option>
  <option value="Plus" data-cost="29.99">Plus</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to do this.  As I said I'm new to jQuery so this was extremely helpful!